# Solve linear equation system with variable real number?

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you solve the following system of linear equations:
$2x_1 + (3+a)x_2 + 2x_3 = 2+a$

$x_1 + ax_2 + 2x_3 = a$

$ax_1 + 2x_2 + 2ax_3 = 0$

assuming that $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$? I feel confident in solving linear equation systems with just constants as the coefficients but the variable coefficient $a$ is what gives me problems.

Here is the solution I find:
[solution as augmented matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRMIU.png)
but how would the assumption about `a` make the reduced echelon form any different compared to an assumption about e.g. $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Have you tried Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes and I do get a solution set that includes a but why is the "assume that a is..." important for this equation system? I mean, why is it necessary to assume something about a if there is a general solution set anyway?

Comment: Did you ever divide by $a^2-2$?  That's the most obvious reason for the condition.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for taking the time to help me :) I updated the OP a little with my found solution set. I never used the assumption about `a` for any EROs because but shouldn't it also work if you applied it AFTER you found the general solution set? Please see my updated question (last part)

Comment: No. This system is inconsistent if $a=\pm\sqrt2$. More generally, the rank of the coefficient matrix can be different for different values of any variable coefficients, so you have to analyze the system separately for each exceptional case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $$x_1=a-ax_2-2x_3$$ can we eliminate $$x_1$$:
$$x_2(3-a)-2x_3=2-a$$
$$x_2(2-a^2)+4ax_3=-a^2$$
And then using $$x_3=\frac{x_2(3-a)-(2-a)}{2}$$ to eliminate $$x_3$$.
Then you will get
$$x_2(2-a^2)+2a(3-a)x_2-2a(2-a)=-a^2$$

Comment: Thanks but how are you using the assumption that $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$? I have been told that the solution set for the equation system is different when assuming that $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$ and $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I was not ready yet.

Comment: Ahh sry haha :) I'll get some coffee and come back in a little then :)

Comment: Where did you get the solutions for all the x variables?

Comment: From your system, at first $$x_1$$, then $$x_3$$ and we get an equation only in $$x_2$$ including the parameters.

Comment: Okay, so does the equation for $x_2$ mean, with the assumption that $a \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$, that there is no solution to the equation system? If so, why exactly? What if you now assumed that $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: That is the final question. Then, I will "accept" your answer :) Thanks

Comment: Hello, thanks for your nice report, i will answer your question in a few minutes.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry i have found a mistake in my calculations, eliminating $$x_1$$ we get $$x_2(3-a)-2x_3=2-a$$ this is correct, but the next line must be $$x_2(2-a^2)=a^2$$

Comment: so when $$a=\pm \sqrt{2}a$$ we get NO solutions.

Comment: I hope your are happy now?!

Comment: I am. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I wish you a very nice day!